# File not found on Azure web server

Tags: asp.net, html, azure, ftp, web-deployment

I have a website that has a video background on it's homepage. The video get's fetched from the folder 'videowall'. The live version of the site doesn't play the video and I get 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' in the developer tools window. I checked the root folder of the FTP server and the folder was there.

The portion of the code that plays the video :

```
            <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume="0" poster="~/video/oranges.jpg" muted="muted">
            <source src="/videowall/pete.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <%--<source src="~/video/oranges.webm" type="video/webm" />--%>
            <source src="/videowall/pete.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        </video>
```

The path of the file is relative to the root directory. Why is the FTP server not able to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a custom mime type in the web.config to serve the mp4 file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
           <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can reference the following links:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/79eb0c22-fe78-41d6-ac57-03055610b2a8/mp4-media-files-on-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: Awesome. Can you please mark this as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry.Don't have enough points to approve it as an answer :(